# Using Composer autoload inside a ZIP package

Tags: composer-php

I've been trying to get composer to generate classmaps for an API provided by a 3rd party company (OtherCompany in the example configuration) but have been unable to get it to work the way I think it should. However, I'm very new to composer so I may be completely wrong.

The situation is as follows. I have a project directory which contains the following composer.json (which **does not** generate classmaps for api.php):

```
{
    "name": "company/company-library",
    "description": "A useful library",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "company",
            "email": "hello@company.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "othercompany/otherlibrary": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\CompanyLib\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "othercompany/otherlibrary",
                "type": "library",
                "description": "Eases the integration of othercompany APIs into company's useful library",
                "homepage": "https://otherlibraryportal.othercompany.com",
                "version": "1.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "../../../../repository/othercompany-otherlibrary-1.2.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "php": ">=5.6.1",
                    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "3.0.18"
                },
                "config": {
                    "optimize-autoloader": true
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["api.php"]
                },
                "minimum-stability": "dev"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The package "othercompany/otherlibrary" is contained in a ZIP file which only contains 2 files **in a folder** named othercompany-otherlibrary-1.2:

```
api.php
readme.txt
```

After a 'compose install', these files are stored in the directory:

```
vendor/othercompany/otherlibrary
```

The api.php file contains a number of classes which I would like to autoload. However, using the configuration above and various modifications of the classmap directive, have not been able to achieve the desired effect. Only if I move the classmap directive to the root level autoload directive in composer.json and update the path to vendor/othercompany/otherlibrary/api.php, classmaps are generated for the package my libary depends on. Snippet:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\CompanyLib\\": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": ["vendor/othercompany/otherlibrary/api.php"]
    }
```

Although this works and classmaps are now generated, I cannot help but think that this should not work this way as each package should independently be able to specify autoload options. If this is correct, what would be the right way to specify autoload options for the othercompany/otherlibrary package?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

api.php:

```
<?php

// Creates the API Request from the context
class APIRequest {
}

// API Response 
class APIResponse {
}

// Api Method Type Constants
class APIMethodType {
}

// API Context that contain info for the API endpoint
class APIContext {
}

?>
```

companylibrary.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @package Company Library
 * @author Company < hello@company.com >
 * @version 1.0.0
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

define('WC_CL_VERSION', '1.0.0');

require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Classes are correctly autoloaded if the autoload directive for the
 * package the 'root' package depends on, is specified at the 'root'
 * package level.
 * 
 * If the autoload directive is specified at the package level of the
 * 'sub' level of the package itself, no classmaps are generated.  
 */ 
$public_key("othercompanypublickey");
$context = new APIContext();
$context->set_api_key('companyapikey');
$context->set_public_key($public_key);
$request = new APIRequest($context);
```

composer.json (which **does** generate classmaps for api.php):

```
{
    "name": "company/company-library",
    "description": "A useful library",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "company",
            "email": "hello@company.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "othercompany/otherlibrary": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\CompanyLib\\": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": ["vendor/othercompany/otherlibrary/api.php"]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "othercompany/otherlibrary",
                "type": "library",
                "description": "Eases the integration of othercompany APIs into company's useful library",
                "homepage": "https://otherlibraryportal.othercompany.com",
                "version": "1.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "../../../../repository/othercompany-otherlibrary-1.2.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "php": ">=5.6.1",
                    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "3.0.18"
                },
                "minimum-stability": "dev"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not extract that package? As far as I know, PHP can't directly load classes from a ZIP file, and Composer doesn't change that

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear enough. I'm not trying to have PHP load classes from a ZIP file. I've defined a package my library depends on as a ZIP file as the 'othercompany' releases their API as such. During a 'composer install', the package is successfully extracted to the vendor/othercompany/otherlibrary folder, including the api.php file which contains the classes. The problem, I think, is that the autoload directive on the othercompany/otherlibrary package level is somehow not working.

Comment: "Somehow not working" sounds strange - are you facing any **specific** problem? Then please share the code involved

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and willingness to dig in deeper Nico. I appreciate that. I've added the additional information you've requested to the question. In addition to this, I will create a small GitHub repository to help investigate this matter.

Comment: Just created a repository on GitHub to demonstrate my issue with composer: https://github.com/ezoer/companylibrary Interestingly, the 'demonstration effect' manifested itself, the sample code on GitHub works exactly the way it should.

Comment: Just updated my main project according to the way I setup my GitHub demonstration project and found one nitty gritty difference in the way the ZIP file was created. In my development environment, I used a compressed **folder** containing the api.php and readme.txt files. However, in my GitHub project I simply zipped the api.php file. So, it turns out that if you compress a folder, classmaps are NOT generated, whereas if you simply compress the files, classmaps are generated correctly. (Note: I ran 'composer clear-cache', deleted the vendor directory and then re-ran 'composer install')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** compress the folder containing the othercompany/otherlibrary files but instead, simply compress the files.

For a working project, please refer to GitHub:

[github.com/ezoer/companylibrary](https://github.com/ezoer/companylibrary)